# Have all tags from all folders appear in tags tab drop-down

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-explorer, tags

I have a Windows 8 and Windows 7 computers.  I have an internal office network and we all share files on an external hard drive connected wirelessly. We are trying to organize these files and the tags option in Windows Explorer seems to be a good option.

The problem is, is that the tags that we have already used only appear in the tags drop-down options if they are on files in the current folder.

I would like to know if it is possible to have all the tags that we have used in the overall folder show up in the drop-down. That way when we want to search for a file in all of the folders the we can click on the tags tab and all of the available tags we have used show up.